# Absolute position for child when parent uses float

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I am doing a setup where two images and a text container are side by side using float left, however I also need to use an overlay div with some text when the user hovers over, but this breaks the display.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent-container">
    <div class="child-container">
      <img src="http://blog.hdwallsource.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/solid-color-wallpaper-21953-22506-hd-wallpapers.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="overlay">
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child-container">
      <img src="http://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Solid-Color-HD-Wallpapers-For-Desktop-768x432.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="child-container-text">
      <p>hhohdoioadoasabs</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.parent-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.child-container {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
}

.child-container img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.child-container-text {
  background-color: #000;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

And here is a CodePen with it: https://codepen.io/leofontes/pen/ORPJWd?editors=1100

Any idea why they are getting stacked? I had used the same trick of absolute positioning for overlays before and it worked, why is the float breaking it?

Thank you

Comment: I also have trouble finding the problem. After messing with the code, I realised it's doing exactly what you'd expect it to do with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/37LsfmLa/
See the fiddle for a working example. (Sorry, I have no clue how codepen works!)

Your question is vague, but I believe this is what you're looking for. The problem with your code is that you gave the images an absolute position, while having them in a floated div. Standard `float` behaviour will collapse any empty div. It will shrink any element to its contents size.
Your elements have their `width` set, which should fix that problem, but there's another: *they have no height*. The result: They collapse. -- note that an elements with `position:absolute` do *not* count as content that stretch their parents.

That's where your problem was. You need to give your divs a static height in order to make something like this work, though I'm wondering why your images even have `position:absolute`? But, whatever floats your boat. (I wouldn't use `position:absolute` on any image that should fill an element, but that's just my preference)

```
.child-container {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}
```

^ the above is what fixed it. A simple `height` property.

Comment: I needed them to be absolute positioned so that I could make the overlay over them. Thank you, that explained why the behavior was happening and solved my problem.

Comment: Personally, I would recommend you to use `background-image` through CSS. This would allow you to use CSS to crop the images, making sure they will always fit within the given dimensions. Then you could use the overlay without having the extra html of an img, or pretty much any other overlay issues. But, that's up to you!